# Prove or find a counter example to those statements.

Tags: functions, continuity

Let the funktions $f,g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

a) $f$ is continuos in $a$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $|f|$ is continuos in a;

b) $f,g$ are continuos in $a$ $\Rightarrow$ $max\{f,g\}$ and $min\{f,g\}$ are continuos in $a$;

c) $f,g$ are continuos in $a$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $f \cdot g$ is continuos in $a$.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Hint: all claimed $\Leftarrow$ are false with simple counterexmples

Comment: Please, thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question  [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/search), and please read [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

**(a)** You may use the  $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition of continuity,  the [reverse triangle inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214067/triangle-inequality-for-subtraction/214069#214069).

**(b)**  [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675481/if-f-g-are-continuous-at-a-show-that-hx-max-fx-gx-and-kx-mi)  the first answer is a hint, and I think you can continue.

**(c)** Check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432667/is-the-product-of-continuous-functions-in-a-metric-space-continuous) hint.